# How do I stop multiple bookmarklets from appearing?

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

I am in the process of making a bookmarklet that pops up a div with various things in it... when you click on the link to open the bookmarklet twice, two bookmarklets pop up. how do I prevent this from happening?

index.html:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Bookmarklet Home Page</title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" />
</head>
<body>
<a href="javascript:(function(){code=document.createElement('SCRIPT');code.type='text/javascript';code.src='code.js';document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(code)})();">click here</a>
</body>
</html>
```

code.js:

```
function toggle_bookmarklet() {
    bookmarklet = document.getElementById("bookmarklet");
    if (bookmarklet.style.display == "none") {
        bookmarklet.style.display = "";
    }
    else {
        bookmarklet.style.display = "none";
    }
}
div = document.createElement("div");
div.id = "bookmarklet";
div.style.margin = "auto";
div.style.position = "fixed";
content = "";
content += "<a href='javascript:void(0);'><div id='xbutton' onClick='javascript:toggle_bookmarklet();'>x</div></a>";
div.innerHTML = content;
document.body.appendChild(div);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just check for the existence of `div` before creating it.

```
var div = document.getElementById("bookmarklet");
if (!div)
{
    div = document.createElement("div");
    div.id = "bookmarklet";
    div.style.margin = "auto";
    div.style.position = "fixed";
}
```

Also, since you already have a global reference to `div`, you don't need to search for it by id in `toggle_bookmarklet`.  You can just reference `div`.  I'd try to choose a more unique name though, so as to avoid running in to naming collisions.

**Edit:** For that matter, if you are going to use a global variable, you can simplify further.  Don't even bother giving it an id, just use the global reference:

```
function toggle_bookmarklet() {
    bookmarkletEl.style.display = bookmarkletEl.style.display == "none" ? "" : "none";
}
if (!window.bookmarkletEl) {
    var bookmarkletEl = ddocument.createElement("div");
    bookmarkletEl.style.margin = "auto";
    bookmarkletEl.style.position = "fixed";
}
```